# Select Query to get last 3 calls and mails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. One of tables has all mails from users and other table has all calls from users.

```
Table 1
call_id, | call_date | user_id 
1        |   10/01/12|    3 
2        |   9/01/12 |    3 

Table 2 
mail_id, | mail_date | user_id
1        |   8/01/12 |    3
2            7/01/12 |    3
```

I need to get last last 3 calls and mails : 
10/01/12 - call
9/01/12  - call
8/01/12  - mail

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?  Always for exactly one user_id, or 3 records per user_id, for all users?

Comment: Always for exactly one user_id. This is MySql DataBase. Sorry, that did not specify question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming MySQL, and for just one User_ID...

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
(
  SELECT 'call' AS type, id, call_date AS event_date, user_id FROM table_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mail' AS type, id, mail_date AS event_date, user_id FROM table_2
)
  data
WHERE
  user_id = 3
ORDER BY
  event_date DESC
LIMIT
  3
```

**EDIT:** Ooops, forgot to specify `DESC` in the `ORDER BY`, sorry.

Comment: Here how he will get last 3 calls and 3 mails? as you are selecting with limit 3?"

Comment: @AnandPhadke - The example the OP gives has 4 input records and 3 output records. The requirement is not for 3 of each, but 3 in total, taking into account the date of each individual record.

Comment: oh ok sorry I did not get his requirement.But in your answer you are just putting all recods from both the tables together and selecting top 3 for user id=3.So how will you make sure this will get the last mail in the output?

Comment: @AnandPhadke - The `UNION` includes the `date` field *(aliased to a common name)*, then order all the results by the field, then limits to 3 results.

Comment: What if all mails are latest and calls come after that in that case he will only get latest mails or latest calls(if all cals are latest than mails).He will not get mix of last 3 calls and mails

Comment: @AnandPhadke - Correct.  That is *(as far as I understand)* exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @user1595557 - Please upvote answers that have helped you, and accept the one answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @userID int;
SET @userID=3;

select call_id FROM table_1 
where user_id=@userID
order by call_date desc limit 2

UNION ALL

select mail_id FROM table_2
where user_id=@userID
order by mail_date desc limit 1
```

Comment: That will return up to 6 records.  The OP wants at most 3 records.

Comment: He says last 3 calls and mails rite?

Comment: Then gives an example including 2 calls and 1 mail.

Comment: That always returns 2 calls and 1 mail.  What if all the mails happened more recently than all the calls?  Then the OP would want 0 calls and 3 mails...

Comment: I guess here OP needs to fetch last 2 calls and 1 mail

Comment: OP is not saying anything :-)